# Variable Scope Between JS Functions: Variable Not Defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am working on a script that uses jQuery get function to send information to another page and return the data as an alert on current page. I am trying to send the search field value from input form (this works), as well as the collector ID, which is a value generated by an option selected in a drop down menu above the search form.

Unfortunately, I keep getting "collector_id is undefined error" when I run the script. I think I am having an issue with the scope of the variable.. but have tried many options and can't seem to find the solution which keeps the value of collector_id for use in the get function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

      $( ".search-field" ).keyup(function() {

//THIS FUNCTION UPDATES THE COLLECTOR ID VARIABLE FROM DROPDOWN MENU VALUE SELECTED BY USER
$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var collector_id = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      collector_id += $( this ).data('value') + " ";
    });
  })
  .change();

//THIS FUNCTION DOES A SEARCH ON ANOTHER PHP SCRIPT PASSING search and collector_id values
  if($(".search-field").val().length > 3) {
    var search = $(".search-field").val(); 
  $.get("query-include.php" , {search: search, collector_id: collector_id})
    .done(function( data ) {
      alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    });
  }
   }); 

  });
```

Comment: Please fix your intendation. It's nearly impossible to reason about code that is not properly indented.

Comment: `collector_id` is a variable scoped to the `change` handler. There's no `collector_id` defined anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to initialize collector_id outside of the change, so it will be in scope for the $.get

```
var collector_id = "";
$( "select" )
.change(function () {
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
        collector_id += $( this ).data('value') + " ";
    });
})
.change();

//THIS FUNCTION DOES A SEARCH ON ANOTHER PHP SCRIPT PASSING search and collector_id values
if($(".search-field").val().length > 3) {
    var search = $(".search-field").val(); 
    $.get("query-include.php" , {search: search, collector_id: collector_id})
    .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    });
}
});
```